# Biopython: Weight Intervals and Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, biopython

Hopefully someone familiar with Biopython can help me out. I have a function that takes FASTA files (DNA sequence files) and creates a dictionary with the sequence ID as the key and the molecular weight of the sequence as the value. Since sequences can be ambiguous, I also have a function that spits out all possible real sequences from the ambiguous one and uses that as input for the dictionary-making function that I just described; I integrated it into the dictionary-creating function so that for ambiguous sequences, the function spits out a minimum and maximum molecular weight values for the possible real sequences represented by the ambiguous one.

```
def seq_ID_and_weight(file_name):
    with open (file_name) as file:
        ID_weight = {} #create an empty dictionary
        for sequence in SeqIO.parse(file,'fasta'):
            weight_min = 10000
            weight_max = 0
            all_poss_sequences = ambiguous_to_unambiguous(sequence.seq) # only call the function once and store it in variable to improve performance
            if len(all_poss_sequences) != 1: #if the length would be 1, its unambiguous
                for possib in all_poss_sequences:
                    if SeqUtils.molecular_weight(possib) < weight_min: 
                        weight_min = SeqUtils.molecular_weight(possib)
                    elif SeqUtils.molecular_weight(possib) > weight_max:
                        weight_max = SeqUtils.molecular_weight(possib)
                ID_weight[sequence.id] = [weight_min, weight_max]
            else:
                ID_weight[sequence.id] = [SeqUtils.molecular_weight(sequence.seq)]
        return ID_weight
```

The function spits out something like this, where the values are either the definitive molecular weight of the sequence (if the seq is unambiguous) or the min and max of the possible molecular weights of the sequence (if seq is ambiguous):

{'seq_7009': [6236.9764, 6367.049999999999], 'seq_418': [3716.3642000000004, 3796.4124000000006], 'seq_9143_unamb': [4631.958999999999]}

However, now I need to use this function to make a new one that does something slightly different. The new function needs to take a FASTA file name and min and max molecular weights as inputs and return a list of sequence IDs for sequences that have a molecular weight within that interval. Basically, the function should return the ID of an ambiguous sequence for which the weight interval overlaps the weight interval that you specify.

My approach to this would be as follows:

1. Initialize a dictionary containing the output of the previous function, like the example I gave above.
2. Iterate over the dictionary, checking if the key has only one value or multiple (a tuple).

a. If only one value, then check if the value is in the given range, and if so, print that sequence ID. If not, break (do nothing).

b. If multiple values, then check if either the first or second is in the given range (because if so, there is some overlap). If so, print that sequence ID. If not, break.

How would I actually implement this? This is all I have so far - I've really only created the dictionary:

```
def find_sequence(file_name, min_weight, max_weight):
    with open (file_name) as file:
        dictionary = {}
        dictionary.update(seq_ID_and_weight(file_name))
        for key in dictionary:
```

Now I need to check how many values the keys have, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to traverse the dictionary & check the first 2 values.

This is the approach.

```
def find_sequence(file_name, min_weight, max_weight):
        li=[] # list to store ids

        with open (file_name) as file:
            dictionary = {}
            dictionary.update(seq_ID_and_weight(file_name))  
            for k,v in dictionary.items(): # traverse the dictionary
                for i in range(min(2,len(v))): # if len(v) > 2 , then it range will be 2 else 1
                    if v[i]>min_weight and v[i]<max_weight: # if value is within range append the sequence_id to list
                        li.append(k)
                        break

        return li
```